# radio button in google form with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, radio-button, google-forms

I was writing a web scraper in python using selenium  on a google form page, but i want to be able to select a particular button that i want. i tired selecting all the buttons once so it ended up selecting the last one as expected. Going through a multiple of a number is also not possible as each contain different number of buttons.

So i want a way to get the number of radio buttons in a group and a way to select the desired one.

[Test site](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeWJKoj2LG14pgNOaQOTBnDeXH6NNw8c90Q5mfcFeNNr75HMg/viewform)

If there are any other suggestions then i will be happy to listen ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import Resources
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= Resources.driverChrome)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(Resources.linkTest)

time.sleep(3)
try:
    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
    if email.is_displayed() & email.is_enabled():
        email.send_keys(Resources.emailTest)
except:
    print("Email box was not found")

containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class ='freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer']")
sNoBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' ] ")




time.sleep(2)
radios = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio exportOuterCircle']")

for radio in radios:
    radio.click()

for container in containers:

    sNo = int(containers.index(container))
    print("\n\n" + str(sNo) + "    " + container.text)


button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]")
button.click()

time.sleep(3)

try:
    viewScore = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'View score')]").click()

except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

**First, you can find all radio buttons on the webpage with the following code:**

```py
radiobuttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer")
```

Result: a list of radio button elements

**Next, you are going to count the radio buttons.** Note that radio buttons are global; The radio button "Option 2" is the 11th button instead of 2nd. **If you want to click the very first radio button, use:**

```py
radiobuttons[0].click()
```

Result: the radio button is clicked

**To click the n th radio button, use:**

```py
radiobuttons[n-1].click()
```